# Running Asky BrowserQuest on localhost

Tags: html, node.js, localhost

I've been trying to run Askys version of BrowserQuest on my local machine - but without any luck.

Im getting the following errors when im trying to start the server:

```
  server/js/databasehandler.js error message:
  var cls = require("./lib/class"),
  Player = require('./player'),
  Messages = require("./message"),
  redis = require("redis"),
  client = redis.createClient(xxxx, xxxx, {socket_nodelay: true});
```

I also tried to change `xxxx xxxx` to port and host of my redis server (databasehandler.js file), when I'm getting another error: `Unexpected number`.

Askys BrowserQuest:
https://github.com/browserquest/BrowserQuest-Asky

Is there any differences between the regular version and Askys when it comes to installing it? I have the original version of BrowserQuest up and running but Asky's doesnt work whatsoever, been following the readmes and the "tutorial" from
https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest/tree/master/server.